# Is Adobe-Brackets compatible with browsers other than Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, web, adobe-brackets

Can `adobe-brackets` be used with any browsers other than chrome? 
If so, how can I implement it?

Comment: Is this a question about `adobe-brackets`? Your current tags make it look like you're talking about punctuation on the web

Comment: sorry..my english is not very well .so i didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Enable `File > Enable Experimental Live Preview`.
You can then start Live Preview, which will initially be opened in your default browser. But the thing is, you can copy the page's URL to any other browser (Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, ...) and all will be live-updated simultaneously.

More info:

- [Multibrowser Live Preview in the Wiki (outdated)](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Live-Preview-Multibrowser)
- [Release 1.1 announcement](http://blog.brackets.io/2014/12/18/brackets-1-1-and-extract-for-brackets-0-6-now-available/)

Comment: but when i change the default brower,it also will be opened in Chrome.i would ask if Chrome is the only option which supported by Brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [brackets.io](http://brackets.io). If so, the only supported browser is chrome (it's mentioned under Brackets Highlights - Live Preview - Other limitations) https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets